# How to count certain word in string using C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

How to counting the same word in a string

**Input**

*Number of String*

String1 = dadymathewdadreadad

String2 = sdgfghhjdjrjjyjjrtfdhe

Search = dad

**Output**

Number of dad in string1 = 3

Number of dad in string2 = 0

### Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    string str[50];
    int n;

    cin>>n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n;i++) {
        cin>>str[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 50;i++) {
        if(substr(i,4) == "dad"){
            n += 1;
        }

    }
    cout<<n;
    return 0;
}
```

### ERROR

> In function 'int main()':
>       [Error] 'substr' was not declared in this scope

Comment: [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) is your friend

Comment: You forgot to call `substr` on the object: `str.substr(i,4)`. Vote to close as typo. Also you can do `cin >> str`.

Comment: @bolov `str` is an array

Comment: There are *multiple* problems with your code, besides the error you get. For example, is `n` the number of strings you should read, or the number of matches in each string? It can't be both simultaneously. You also have no bounds checking, neither for the input nor for the checking.

Comment: @acraig5075 oh, yeah, my mistake.

Comment: And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). It's unclear if you ask about the error and how to fix it, or if you ask about "[h]ow to counting the same word in a string".

Comment: `n` is number of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n; 
    string s[50];
    int c;
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>s[i];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        c=0;
        int found=s[i].find("jack");
        while(found!=string::npos){
            found=s[i].find("jack",found+1);
            if(found) c++;
        }
        cout<<c<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One trick you could use here would be to just replace the search term (e.g. `dad`) with empty string, and then compare the length of the string before and after the replacement.

```
string input = "dadymathewdadreadady";
string search = "dad";
int size_orig = input.size();
replace(string, search, "");
cout << "number of 'dad' is: " << (size_orig - input.size()) / search.size();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find()` member function of `std::string`, adjusting the start position after every successful find until the end of the string:

```
#include <string>

int count(const std::string& sentence, const std::string& word)
{
    int total = 0;
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t pos = 0;

    while ((pos = sentence.find(word, start)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        ++total;
        start = pos + word.size();
    }

    return total;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "dadymathewdadreadady";
    int c = count(input, "dad");
    return 0;
}
```